# Using Query String Parameters instead of a "Range:" HTTP Header in Dojo's JsonRest

Tags: json, proxy, dojo, pagination, dgrid

I'm trying to set up pagination in Dojo. I basically have a table with thousands of records, and I want to display them page-by-page to the user instead of all at once.  I'm using dgrid with a JsonRest store.  Per JsonRest's documentation, the store uses HTTP's "Range:" header to perform paging. When a request is made for a range of items, the store will include a "Range:" header with an items range unit specifying the range. (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) Unfortunately this is a big problem because some of our users are behind proxies that filter out HTTP's range header.  The only workaround I see is to use query string parameters instead of the "Range:" HTTP header.  So I'd have a URL that would look something like:
http://myhost.com/myapp/things?start=10&end=19
instead of having the Range Header be "Range: items=0-24"

How would I go about solving this issue? If you have a suggestion for an alternative workaround, that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution to this.  Simply overwrite Dojo's JsonRest class and use it instead of JsonRest when you create your dgrid.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(declare, JsonRest){
    var base = JsonRest;
    return declare("myapp.JsonRest2", base, {

        query: function(query, options){
            if(options.start >= 0 || options.count >= 0){
                query.start = options.start >= 0 ? options.start : 0;
                query.count = options.count >= 0 ? options.count : 10;
            }
            return this.inherited(arguments);
        }
    });
});
```